# Ciclo for auto? c++

Tags: c++

he visto que existe un for algo extraño (soy algo nuevo) que decía algo parecido a esto

```
   for(auto: x){
------codigo-------
}
```

He intentando buscar sobre este ciclo, pero no encuentro mucha ayuda, la mayoría esta en inglés pero no viene para que sirve solo esta puesta en algunos ejercicios que otros hicieron pero muy grandes. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El ejemplo es en c++:

```
int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 10, 20, 30, 40 };

    for (int x : arr)
        cout << x << endl;
}
```

La salida es:
10
20
30
40

Es una implementacion de un foreach. Espero te ayude